# schema error when using fs.createWriteStream to write data to bigquery (node.js)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

Error : `No schema specified on job or table`.

No idea why this error is happening. The code is from documentation. I have also tried following a different format such fs.createWriteStream({sourceFormat: "json"}) - but it results in the same error.

```
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bigquery.dataset("firebase_test_data");
const table = dataset.table("flattened_data");
const fs = require("fs");

fs.createReadStream("./data.json")
  .pipe(table.createWriteStream("json"))
  .on("job", (job) => {
    // `job` is a Job object that can be used to check the status of the
    // request.
    console.log(job);
  })
  .on("complete", (job) => {
    // The job has completed successfully.
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was getting this error since the table defined in `const table = dataset.table("flattened_data");`  doesn’t have the appropriate schema which you are passing in data.json.

tried the following code as per the [Google documentation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Table.html#createWriteStream-examples) and specified the schema of table in BigQuery which successfully loads data into the table.

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const bigquery = new BigQuery();
const dataset = bigquery.dataset('my-dataset');
const table = dataset.table('my-table');

//-
// Load data from a JSON file.
//-
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream('/path-to-json/data.json')
 .pipe(table.createWriteStream('json'))
 .on('job', (job) => {
   // `job` is a Job object that can be used to check the status of the
   // request.
 })
 .on('complete', (job) => {
   // The job has completed successfully.
 });
```